# SQL query to search for \n or \n\r in nvarchar field in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have nvarchar field in table. Data is stored in with `\n` ,`\n\r` , But I can't see in SQL window  when I copy column data , its already formatted with line break for `\n` ,`\n\r` .

But I can see when i debug(asp.net) in code there its showing as string.

I want to see query this columns to see how many records are having `\n`  or `\n\r` but result are not showing. query is as below

```
SELECT temf.str_col FROM dbo.tbl_table1s temf WHERE temf.str_col LIKE '%\n%'
```

How can verify this ?

Comment: In the debugger, new lines are showed with the escape characters. In sql there is no such an escape character. Have you tried it with `like '%' + char(10) + '%'`?

Comment: @Silvermind it should be an answer to the question! I should add that `CHAR(13)` is needed in that case too.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    temf.str_col 
FROM 
    dbo.tbl_table1s temf 
WHERE 
    temf.str_col LIKE '%' + CHAR(10) + '%'
    OR temf.str_col LIKE '%' + CHAR(13) + '%'
    OR temf.str_col LIKE '%' + CHAR(9) + '%' --tabs, optional
```